# C Write Bit in Memory

Tags: c, memory, binary, bit

If I have an 8 bit number like so,
`00101001`,

- how would I replace one of the bits with a 1 (setting the bit)?
- how would I replace one of the bits with a 0?

Currently in my code I have two functions as shown:

```
void ADDSET(unsigned char *signalmask, int SIGNUM) {
    *signalmask = *signalmask | (SIGNUM);
}

void DELSET(unsigned char *signalmask, int SIGNUM) {
    *signalmask = *signalmask &~ SIGNUM;
}
```

With a function call like so:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char signalmask = 41;
    int SIGNUM = 7; // signal 1-8

    ADDSET(&signalmask, SIGNUM);

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason when I output my `signalmask`'s memory address it either doesn't replace/remove the bit, or it does the wrong one. I think this is because the `SIGNUM` is starting at 0 when it should be starting at 1.

**I output using**:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    printf("%d", !!((signalmask << i) & 0x80));
}
```

Can anybody help me?

**Note**:
My `INSET` function works as desired:

```
int INSET(unsigned char signalmask, int SIGNUM){
    unsigned char bitMask = 1 << (SIGNUM - 1);
    if ((signalmask & bitMask) == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to port this code over to the `ADDSET` and `DELSET` functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "when I output my signalmask's memory address": do you output the memory address (which won't change) or the value at the address?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. One uses a `*` right and the other doesnt? Edit: Added my output code to the OP.

Comment: The first line of `INSET` is the answer. You need to convert `SIGNUM` to a bit mask.

Comment: I tried to do just that but got quite a few errors. I'm not sure of the exact syntax since the value coming in has a `*` before it and in `INSET` it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the description of the signum (`=7`) the code should look similar to :

```
void addSet(unsigned char *signalMask, int sigNum) 
{ // turn bit ON
    *signalMask = *signalMask | (1<<sigNum);
} // end function: addSet

void selSet(unsigned char *signalMask, int sigNum) 
{ // turn bit OFF
    *signalMask = *signalMask & ~(1<<sigNum);
}
```

I would also check that signum was in the range (`0...31`)

> General practice is only macro names and constants are all CAPS.

- Using 'camel case' for function names and parameter names is expected and very readable (although separating individual words with an '_' is acceptable)
- Using all lower case for names makes reading/understanding the code more difficult

Comment: This code seems to be off by one. Using a sigNum of 1 changes bit 2 (coming from the least significant bit). Any ideas?

Comment: I got it, I just - 1! Haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An equivalent, but slightly more compact syntax is:

```
void ADDSET(unsigned char *signalmask, int SIGNUM) {
    *signalmask |= (1 << SIGNUM);
}

void DELSET(unsigned char *signalmask, int SIGNUM) {
    *signalmask &= ~(1 << SIGNUM);
}
```

If you simply want to toggle whatever is there (i.e. `1->0` or `0->1`):

```
void TOGGLESET(unsigned char *signalmask, int SIGNUM) {
    *signalmask ^= (1 << SIGNUM);
}
```